# сколько выполнений цикла понадобилось для получения выигрышной комбинации

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

dots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

my_ticket = [2, 3, 8, 'd']

while True:
    my_ticket != random.sample(dots, 4)
    if my_ticket == random.sample(dots, 4):
        print("you win")
        break
```

из данного цикла надо узнать сколько комбинации понадобилось пока не вышла выбранная комбинация. спасибо большое!

Comment: 47652 комбинации.  Пожалуйста.

Comment: спасибо но мне бы так чтобы программа сама напечатала этот ответ, если это в твоих возможности редактируй код и покажи мне на примере..

Comment: Извини, такие вещи нужно делать самостоятельно.

Comment: Можешь задать переменную под счетчик, а потом ее вывести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

dots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

my_ticket = [2, 3, 8, 'd']
number_combinations = 0
while True:
    my_ticket != random.sample(dots, 4)
    number_combinations += 1
    if my_ticket == random.sample(dots, 4):
        print("you win")
        print("The winning combination was: {}".format(number_combinations))
        break
```